# Regex to match variables only when inside quotes

Tags: regex, pcre

I have many sql files. I am trying to locate files that contain a variable (format of `@varname`) ONLY if they appear within matching single or double quotes. I only care that it exists and is there, I just need to know the files that this occurs in.

I can match all the quoted strings, but can't figure out how to test that even just a single `@` char appears within the match

matching single and double quote pairs `(["'])(.*?)\1`

example file:

> ...sql statements
>
> select @sql = 'select * from
> Users where id = @id '
>
> ...more sql statements

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is a better example file, with comments (sql comments) on which statements should match and examples of ones that shouldn't

```
...sql statements

-- only this quoted string would match
select @sql = "select * from 
    Users where id = @id "

-- other statements that wouldn't match because not in a pair of quotes
if ltrim(isnull(@stat,'')) <> '' and @stat <> '""'
begin
    select @sql = @sql + " and Stat in ("+@stat+")"
end
if isnull(@atype,'') <> '' 
begin
    select @sql = @sql + " and Type in ("+@atype+")"
end

...more sql statements
```

Comment: Something like `(?s)(["'])((?:(?!\1)[^@])*@.*?)\1`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That is really close! It is giving some false positives, I have updated the question to include some examples of things that shouldn't be matched

Comment: What a mind blowing thing... Try `(?m)(?:^\h*--.*|(["'])(?:(?!\1)[^@])*\1)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?s)(["'])(?:(?!\2)[^@])*@.*?\2`, see https://regex101.com/r/lS8F9f/1/

Comment: Have you had time to check it?

Answer (score 1):

For the sample text given....

**Try:**

```
(?:\s|=)(?:\"[^"]*@[^"]*\"|(?:\s|=)\'[^']*@[^']*\')
```

**Demo:**

- https://regex101.com/r/BXcYt4/1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using PCRE and to

> to test that even just a single @ char appears within the match

You can use an alternation excluding either `"` or `'` and also exclude matching an `@` adding it to the negated character class.

To get both values in the same group, you can use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html).

```
=\h*(?|"([^"@]*@[^"@]+)"|'([^@']*@[^'@]*)')
```

The pattern matches:

- `=\h*` Match `=` and optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `"(` Match `"` and start **group 1**

    - `[^"@]*@` Match optional chars other than `"` or `@` and then match `@`
    - `[^"@]+` Match 1+ chars other than `"` or `@`
  - `)"` Close group 1 and atch `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `'([^@']*@[^'@]*)'` The same as previous pattern, this time for `'`
- `)` Close branch reset group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L7a6dr/1)